# Symmetric random walk on a regular hexagon

Tags: probability

I wonder if there is any trick in this problem. The following graph is a regular hexagon with its center $C$ and one of the vertices $A$. There are $6$ vertices and a center on the graph, and now assume we perform the symmetric random walk on it. Suppose the random walk starts from $A$. Given now the process is at one of the vertices, then it has probability $\frac{1}{3}$ for entering into $C$ for the next step, and $\frac{1}{3}$ probability for moving to its two neighbors respectively as well. We want to compute the probability of this random process started from $A$ and finally return to $A$, and it must not go through $C$ before its first arrival back to $A$.

[image]

Therefore, basically $A$ and $C$ are two absorbing states. Denote this discrete random walk as $\left\{ X_{t} \right\}_{t\geq 0}$, and I want to compute:

$$
P(X_{t} = A, ~ X_{s} \notin \left\{A, C \right\} \mbox{ for } \forall ~ 0 < s < t ~ | ~ X_{0} = A)
$$

The following are my thoughts:

The first intuition came to me was DTMC by regarding $A$ and $C$ as two absorbing states and the process absorbed by $A$ eventually. This requires me to write down a probability transition matrix and then solve linear equations. However, it is actually an interviewing question, so I suppose there is a much easier way to do this.

Also, by intuition I think by constructing a stopping time might help, but my thought just stuck at here.

Comment: Consider the $7 \times 7$ Markov matrix (containing the transitions probabilities $1/3, 1/3, 1/3$ in each line).

Comment: This problem which belongs to the category "first-return to origin" can be "unfolded" into restricted walks into this brick-like lattice as shown in this recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489077/305862).

Comment: You can reduce the number of elements in the transition probability matrix from $7^2$ down to $5^2$ if you consider the two states adjacent to $A$ as being in the state "$1$ away from $A$", and the same for the states on the hexagon that are two steps away from $A$.

Answer (score 7):

We can look at this graph as an electric network where every edge has conductance $c(xy)=1$ (and hence resistance $1$ as well) where $xy$ represents an edge. We label the hexagon with $ABCDEF$, and the center of the hexagon as $O$. Then we want to look at $$\mathbb P(\tau_A^+<\tau_O)$$ Note that $\mathbb P(\tau_A^+<\tau_O)+\mathbb P(\tau_A^+>\tau_O)=1$, so we try and find $$\mathbb P(\tau_A^+>\tau_O)$$

This is an escape problem! We are trying to calculate the probability that a random walk starting at $A$ 'escapes' to $O$ before coming back to $A$. This is precisely where electric networks shine. By a standard theorem, we have that

$$\mathbb P(\tau_A^+>\tau_O)=\frac{r(A)}{R_{eff}^{AO}}$$

where $r(A)=\frac{1}{c(A)}=\frac{1}{\sum_{x|x\sim A}c(Ax)}=\frac1{1+1+1}=\frac13$ and $R_{eff}^{AO}$ is the effective resistance between $A$ and $O$. This effective resistance is what we want to find out.

Here is the circuit (apologies for the bad diagram)

[image: Circuit 1]

We exploit the symmetry in the figure to make lives simpler. Since current enters through $A$ ($A$ is the source), by symmetry $B$ and $F$ are at equal voltages. Similarly $C$ and $E$ are at same voltages. Thus the following pairs of resistances are in parallel

$$(AF,AB),\ (FE,BC),\ (ED,CD)$$

This inadvertently makes the following pairs also in parallel (check the potentials at the end and note that they are the same)

$$(OF,OB),\ (OE,OC)$$

Gluing all the same voltage points together, and using the parallel law, we get the following circuit

[image: Circuit 2]

where the $500m$ just means $1/2$ units of resistance (the applet I used to draw these diagrams measures these in ohms and milliohms, hence the m). This circuit, drawn in a better way, looks like

[image: Circuit 3]

Now note that the resistances at the extreme right are in series (the $1$ and $1/2$ unit ones at the end), and thus you can replace them with a $1+1/2=3/2=1.5$ unit resistance using the series law. This gets us

[image: Circuit 4]

Now again note that the $1.5$ unit resistance and the $1/2$ unit resistance at the extreme end are in parallel, so using the parallel law, you can replace them with a resistance of unit $\frac{1}{1/(1.5)+1/(1/2)}=3/8=0.375$, giving us the circuit

[image: Circuit 5]

Continuing similarly, you finally end with a resistance of unit $9/20$ which is the effective resistance $R_{eff}^{AO}$ we were looking for. Plugging this in, we get

$$\mathbb P(\tau_A^+>\tau_O)=\frac13\frac{20}9=20/27$$

Finally, putting this in the equation for total probability gives us

$$\mathbb P(\tau_A^+<\tau_O)=1-\mathbb P(\tau_A^+>\tau_O)=1-\frac{20}{27}=\frac7{27}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Fantastic answer !

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Label the vertices of the hexagon as in the diagram below.  Let $\ P_i\ $ be the probability that the walk returns to $\ A\ $ from $\ B_i\ $ without visiting $\ C\ $.  Then, by symmetry, $\ P_4=P_2\ $ and $\ P_5=P_1\ $, and
\begin{align}
P_1&=\frac{1+P_2}{3}\\
P_2&=\frac{P_1+P_3}{3}\\
P_3&=\frac{P_2+P_4}{3}\\
&=\frac{2P_2}{3}\ .
\end{align}
The unique solution of these linear equations is
\begin{align}
P_1&=\frac{7}{18}\\
P_2&=\frac{1}{6}\\
P_3&=\frac{1}{9}\ .
\end{align}
The probability that the walk starting from $\ A\ $ will return to $\ A\ $ before visiting $\ C\ $ is therefore
$$
\frac{P_1+P_5}{3}=\frac{2P_1}{3}=\frac{7}{27}\ .
$$

[image]

**Acknowledgement**

Thanks to HackR for picking up the error in the solution I originally gave for the linear equations, which I have now fixed.

Comment: Some error in your probabilities it seems. I am calculating $P_1=7/18,\ P_2=1/6,\ P_3=1/9$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for picking it up.

Comment: [+1] In fact, it must be said it is a classical method (see for example Theorem 8.12 in this [document](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~fewster/325/notes/ch8.pdf))